# How to push and sort of object array to tree by typescript and javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, recursion

How can I push and sort of object array to a tree by typescript or javascript?

I have 3 object arrays from API  like this:

```
const dataParts = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Part 1",
    "chapterID": [11,12],
    "order": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Part 2",
    "chapterID": [13],
    "order": 2
  }
]

const dataChapters = [
  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Chapter 1"
    "criteriasID": [15,16]
    "order": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Chapter 2",
    "criteriasID": [],
    "order": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "title": "Chapter 1",
    "criteriasID": [],
    "order": 1,
  }
]

const dataCriterias = [
  {
    "id": 15,
    "title": "criteria 1",
    "order": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "title": "criteria 2",
    "order": 2,
  }
]
```

How can I push element and sort it by "order" properties ?

result I want like this:

```
const dataTree = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Part 1",
    "chapterID": [11,12],
    "order": 1,
    "children": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "title": "Chapter 1"
          "criteriasID": [15, 16]
          "order": 1,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 15,
              "title": "criteria 1",
              "order": 1,
            },
            {
              "id": 16,
              "title": "criteria 2",
              "order": 2,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "title": "Chapter 2",
          "criteriasID": [],
          "order": 2,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Part 2",
    "chapterID": [13],
    "order": 2,
    "children": [
        {
          "id": 13,
          "title": "Chapter 1",
          "criteriasID": [],
          "order": 1,
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Do you have any idea about this issue? recursive can do this issue? please help me because this is my thesis graduation

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `map` & `forEach` loop to get the desired result. Inside map you will find the object & append it to the children property.

```js
const dataParts = [{"id": 1,"title": "Part 1","chapterID": [11,12],"order": 1,},{"id": 2,     "title": "Part 2", "chapterID": [13],     "order": 2   } ]

const dataChapters = [{"id": 11,"title": "Chapter 1","criteriasID": [15,16],"order": 1,},{"id": 12,  "title": "Chapter 2", "criteriasID": [],     "order": 2, },   { "id": 13,  "title": "Chapter 1",     "criteriasID": [],     "order": 1,} ]

const dataCriterias = [{"id": 15,"title": "criteria 1","order": 1,},{"id": 16, "title": "criteria 2", "order": 2,   } ];

const find =(arr, obj) => arr.map(a=>obj.find(l=>l.id==a));

const result = dataParts.map(o=>{
    let children = find(o.chapterID, dataChapters);
    children.forEach(t=>{
        t.children = find(t.criteriasID, dataCriterias)
    });
    return {...o, children}
});

console.log(result);
```